# Unable to locate package snort

Tags: kali-linux, snort

I am having problem with installing `snort` on Kali. 
I used the command:

```
sudo apt-get install snort -y
```

but it replies only that unable to locate the package error.
I did upgrade, update, edit `sources.list` and did this one too:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

then I tried to fix broken with:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

and then removed unneccesary of 650MB files with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then finally:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Still same issue however it is only about snort but nothing else. I am not misspelling or anything because I copied the command as well as typed over and over still no result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to locate package snort\_Kali LInux in VMware Workstation Pro (ver 15.5.6)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594935/unable-to-locate-package-snort-kali-linux-in-vmware-workstation-pro-ver-15-5-6)

Comment: It is hard to tell what the issue was without a look at your `sources.list`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that **snort** is not available in any of your current Kali repositories. Add the following repos in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# nano /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
```

Now, save this file and do the following -

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install snort
```

Since Kali is based on Debian, most Ubuntu packages work flawlessly in Kali. Thus, no need to worry about the aforementioned repos. You can also install this package from the source code. But it might require some additional tools.

Comment: its say; http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy Release
404 Not found {IP 019.202.202.202 : 80]
and that respository cant be done securely so therefore disabled by default.

Comment: Comment out the ubuntu repos then, try with the Debian ones instead. Snort might be available in them

Comment: Thanks you so much. This worked perfectly with my digitalocean droplet.

Comment: Hello! You may want to update your answer [according to the documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/#non-kali-repositories): "adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), will break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break."