# Unable to locate package snort_Kali LInux in VMware Workstation Pro (ver 15.5.6)

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, repository, snort

Checked answers to the similar question. Still not working for me.

Current entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
1. deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
2. deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib
3. deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

4. deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
5. deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
```

and then :

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install snort
```

Results in:

```
root@kalibib:~# apt-get install snort
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package snort
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my own question (not on stackexchange). The following should be in source.list for snort to work:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://old.kali.org/kali moto main non-free contrib
```

Comment: Hello! You may want to update your answer according to the current documentation: [Kali Network Repositories](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/)

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, after few days of searching this finaly worked for me.

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

Don't seem to be doing anything though as I got 404 Error.

Comment: Hello. How is this different from the kstatinet's answer above?